# Spring Security - how to validate login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

If I want to specify my own login page with

```
  .formLogin()
  .loginPage("/login")
```

It's not clear to me where I need to Post to.  Do I post to `/login` as well?  Does Spring provide an endpoint with the same name that accepts a post?  What are the responses?  I can't find any documentation that tells me what responses to expect.  I keep getting a 200, no matter what user I enter.

I have a class which implements UserDetailsService and I'm referencing them in my config

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
```

but the `loadUserByUsername` method of that service is not getting called.

If I want to process the login myself by specifying

```
.loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
```

What is expected from that endpoint?

**Update**

My login form is implemented by React.  I got it from elsewhere, so the error handling it's doing might not be relevant for this use case.  I'm trying to understand the return codes I should expect. The code looks something like this

```
 const payload = {
   "email": state.email,
   "password": state.password,
   }
 axios.post( '/login', payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('response.status', response.status);
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    redirectToHome();
                    props.showError(null)
                } else if (response.data.code === 204) {
                    props.showError("Username and password do not match");
                } else {
                    props.showError("Username does not exists");
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

**Update2**

I have `.failureURL("/login?error")` and `.accessDeninedPage("/login?denied)`
When Spring tries to redirect to `/login?denied` I'm seeing this

```
"FORWARD" dispatch for POST "/login?denied", parameters={denied:[]}                                             
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]  
Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 405                                                                     
GET "/login", parameters={}
```

Why is Spring not able to Post to the page.  And then it redirects to `GET "/login"`.
My expectation is that it would do a `GET /login?denied`.  In other words, redirect to my form with an error indication.  But it's doing a POST instead, which is not working

Comment: see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form ... if you want to process the login (form submission) with `.loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")`, the form (rendered by loginPage) should submit to (action=) `/api/login` ... the default form is rendered by [`DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java), a show case: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry if my question wasn't clear.  I've seen both of those links.  My question is, after I post to `/login`, assuming I use the default post processor, what are the responses I should expect to get back?   If I do specify `loginProcessingUrl`, what processing needs to be done?  Is there any reason to not just used the default?  I definitely wan to use my own customer form.  But the processing is probably sufficient.  
 Something else must be wrong with my configuration, because my `loadUserByUsername` method is not even getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing just

```java
formLogin().loginPage("/login")
```

it will configure a POST endpoint with the url `/login` for authentication. The user credential for authentication should contain username and password using the request parameter name `username` and `password` respectively. They can be put in the query string or the posted form data.

If authentication is failed , it will redirect to `/login?error` .

If authentication is successful, it will redirect to the url that you try to visit before login. Or redirect to `/` if that page is the login form.

All of these behaviour are mentioned in the javadoc of the [`loingPage()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.html#loginPage(java.lang.String)) , and [`SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) for the redirect behaviour after successful authentication.

> If I want to process the login myself by specifying
>
> `.loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")`
>
> What is expected from that endpoint?

It will just change the url of the POST endpoint that authenticating user credential to `/api/login`. So your login form should POST to it for authenticating credential . All other behaviour remain unchanged.

Comment: Thank you.  Please see my Update 2.  
As for changing `.loginProcessUrl`, are you saying that just changes the endpoint that Spring creates?  I wasn't sure if specifying a custom url meant that I had to provide it.

Comment: Yes. `loginProcessUrl` configures the url that your login form should POST to for  authenticating the user credential. If you do not specify it , it is equal to the `loginPage` url. Whether you specify  `loginProcessUrl` or not , you also do not need to implement this endpoint by yourself . it is provided by spring-security. hope that clear